# Change Region Format in Settings in simulator but the locale in app doesn't change

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, simulator

I use an instance of NSDateFormatter to help display a date string in my app, but after I change Region Format in Settings in simulator from "United States" to "United Kingdom", the example in settings show date as "5, January 2014", which proves change succeeded. But when I open my app in the simulator, the date is still "Jan 5, 2014".
I used following code to check the locale in my app:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *currentLocale = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier];
NSLog(@"Current locale is %@", currentLocale);
```

And it logs: Current locale is en_US.
It seems that my app doesn't get the current locale in simulator setting. It's supposed to be I change the locale in simulator setting, and my app can reflect the change. Is there anything wrong? 
The date format code is

```
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:item.dateCreated];
```

I am using iOS Simulator version 8.1, Xcode version 6.1.1, iOS 8.1, SDK 8.1

The dateFormatter code is put in the viewWillAppear method of one view controller, after region format changed, and create a new view controller still presents the old locale. Same result even kill the app. I register for locale change notifications in a table view and refresh it. It can reflect the locale change. Couldn't understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It looks like a bug in the simulator: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1063365

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the locale of your `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *currentLocale = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier];
NSLog(@"Current locale is %@", currentLocale);


static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setLocale:locale]; // <- Here

dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:item.dateCreated];
```

Comment: Before setLocale, the currentLocale is still "en_US" after I changed to "United Kingdom" in settings. So [dateFormatter setLocale:locale]; doesn't help.

Comment: It's because Simulator is using your Mac's locale, eventhough you changed locale from simulator settings. If you're testing this on an actual device that line is required.

Comment: Thanks for the device suggestion, though I haven't tried my app on device. I want it work on simulator now. The dateFormatter code is put in the viewWillAppear method of one view controller, after region format changed, and create a new view controller still presents the old region format. Same result even kill the app. I register for locale change notifications in a table view and refresh. It can reflect the locale change. Couldn't understand the difference. Any thought?